# How to create a numeric field for an entity in MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I created an entity within a field and it's type is Whole Number.

I have a problem while entering data into that field i.e 
Suppose I entered `1234567890` but, it displays `1,234,567,890` like this.
I don't want to separate it by comma(`,`)

If I choose a type like Decimal number or floating point number same problem happens.

How can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These settings are driven by the systems and personal user settings.

Have to a look under:

- Crm > Settings > System Settings > Formats for system settings
- Crm > File > Options > Formats for personal users settings

You can customise and change the formatting there.

[image]

Comment: I followed those settings but, these are not satisfying my requirement... In the format settings --> Numbers-->Digit group all options are contains commas and decimal points...  So, its not satisfying my requirement...

Comment: Select the one closet to your formatting/timezone then click customize, there are specific options for numbers

Comment: ThanQ very much...Its Working..!!

Comment: It's Working but there is another problem i.e it is taking the Numbers range from  -2147483648 to 2147483647... If i enter 10 digit number starting with greater than 2 its not taking...How can I avoid this problem...??

Comment: Try the Decimal data type when creating your field, with 10 decimal precision, you can have any number from -100,000,000,000.0000000000 to 100,000,000,000.0000000000. Which is a pretty long number.